# If Year-on-Year quarterly sales growth is negative , how can Y-o-Y profit be increased for a company?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis, profitability

I want to understand how even though quarterly sales has been decreasing for a company , quarterly profit is increasing ?

Is it not the same ?

Please have a look at this image.

[image]

Comment: Not looked at the picture, but remember, at its simplest _profit = revenue - costs_. So if costs went down _more_ than sales/revenue, profit can rise.

Comment: You should compare year-to-year financial report. Since this can be anything, e.g. reduction of cost (employee expenses, tax, loan interest, etc ), deferred income, one-off profit from selling equity,etc.